# How to make ADFS 3.0 pass "whr" parameter to ADFS 2.0 claims provider?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, adfs, ws-federation

I have a next configuration

1. Some web apps based on Dynamics CRM 2013 and portals based on
   SharePoint 2010.
2. Dynamics has claims authentication via ADFS 3.0, SharePoint has via
   ADFS 2.0
3. ADFS 3.0 is federated with ADFS 2.0 which is claims provider trust there.
   So user from ADFS 2.0 can sign in everywhere. Both ADFSs are
   configured to use WS-Federation, not SAML.
4. ADFS 2.0 has several claims provider trusts - AD and other 3rd party ADFSs.
5. ADFS 3.0 is configured to automate home realm discovery on its side,
   but when user lands to ADFS 2.0 he can see home realm discovery page
   there.

Goal is to have maximum automated home realm discovery.

Main question: is it possible to configure/modify/hack ADFS 3.0 to include `whr` parameter with desired claim provider trust when it makes redirect to ADFS 2.0?

I did a debug with fiddler injecting it manually and this approach is working. However searching a web for how-to and no luck.

Currently I see several solution:

1. Add `?whr="<ClaimsProviderId>"` to WS-Federation endpoint like `https://<ADFS2.0URL>/adfs/ls?whr="<ClaimsProviderId>"` in ADFS 3.0 settings. But not sure would it work.
2. Modify `onload.js` to hardcode there redirect with `whr` parameter on ADFS 3.0 side.
3. Do a mod for home realm discovery page on ADFS 2.0 side, which would analyze `wtrealm` parameter from ADFS 3.0 and do selection of desired claims provider.

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard, if possible, on the ADFS3 server itself. 
Have you tried adding it in the RP (CRM and SharePoint)? That should work. Barring some patchlevel solvable issues.

If all users from CRM have to go to the same CP, then your option "3." should work too.